# Do climbers shave limbs?

Tags: rock-climbing

I just bumped into this page at the Bicycles at StackExchange, which talks about [how shaving limbs can help a cyclist](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/44/8605).

Does the same apply to climbers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not as clear cut as for cycling. For cycling you have definite benefits, and of the 3 listed in the accepted answer on the cycling page:

- To prevent infection when crashing.
- To pull off bandages more painlessly after dressing a wound.

Are really not an issue in climbing. Crashes in cycling often cause road rash, where dirt, grit, and hair are forced into a surface wound. This is not your typical climbing injury.

The third one,

- To get a massage of the legs without hair pulling.

Is in my opinion nonsense. You can have a massage just as easily with hairy legs (disclaimer - I don't have hairy legs; I'm going on hearsay from colleagues and friends)

The other answer, around wind resistance, may or may not be true - but in any case it does not apply to climbers :-)